# Issue with a custom view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

How is this possible?

```
PlayingCardView *view = [[PlayingCardView alloc] initWithFrame:currentFrame];
if ([view isKindOfClass:[PlayingCardView class]])
    NSLog(@"checked!");
```

The if below doesn't work. However, it says that my view is of UIView class, not the PlayingCardView, which is inherited from the UIView. The problem is that because of it I can't send PlayingCardView's messages to my view.

update:

```
- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setup];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding initWithFrame in your PlayingCardView class? Is so, post that code.

Comment: - (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setup];
    return self;
}

Comment: Try logging [self class] before and after your call to setup to see what they return.

Comment: If you're claiming that "checked!" doesn't appear when you run the above sequence then clearly either you've not shown us the real code or you screwed up your `init` method royally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you override `initWithFrame` for `PlayingCardView` the wrong way.  You might be doing something like `self = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:]` instead of `self = [super initWithFrame:]`.  Check any `init` methods that you have overridden for `PlayingCardView`.

Comment: Here's the only method I override for PlayinCardView: - (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setup];
    return self;
}

Comment: Check the `init` method of  `PlayingCardView` class' super class. And check if you are returning the correct class type.